# Tomcat HTTP connector - what are good maxThreads/acceptCount values?

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a Java/JSF application that uses Tomcat 7. When the traffic got high, Tomcat manager showed +500 sessions and my app was not accessible anymore even though Tomcat was still running. I had to restart my app. The server was not running out of memory as I have 2,5 GB set for Tomcat, and it never passed from 1,2 GB. Memory dump just showed me a lot of `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Segment` which gave me no hint what the problem is.  I was using HTTP connector with `NIO`. My bonecp connection pool has `max_connections` as 120 and MySQL has `max_connection` of 140.

I'm just giving the context.

After many tests with bonecp configuration, database configuration, I concluded that, with this connector using NIO, I have no more issues in my app:

```
<Connector port="80" 
    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
    connectionTimeout="20000" 
    maxThreads="120"
    redirectPort="8443" />
```

**So my question is**: what is the best value to set for `maxThreads`? Should I set `acceptCount` also? What should I take into consideration for setting these values? Should I consider the `max_connections` from my database?

Thanks

Comment: You're leaking something in your application. Fiddling around with the Tomcat configuration won't fix that. NB This is Tomcat, not Apache. Don't mix them up. Apache is either the name of the entire foundation or else a name for their static HTTP server.

Comment: Thanks @EJP. I am probably leaking something but how come using NIO, I was able to test with JMeter triggering +2000 sessions (JMeter tests) at the same time with no errors? Using BIO I don't have more than 50 successful tests... after that my application dies... (the page I call have a JSF page with a big datatable) So I'll keep the NIO configuration, I just have doubts on what should I take into consideration before setting maxThreads and acceptCount